# If data exists UPDATE else INSERT SQL query - No foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I have a problem, want to make one query that will update if field exists, and insert new one if not. The problem is that id is not unique, so i cant use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

I tried IF EXISTS solution

```
   IF EXISTS (select * from wordpress.wp_4_postmeta where post_id=3466 and meta_key='_job_expires') 
THEN
   update wp_4_postmeta set meta_value='2017-06-25' where post_id=3466 and meta_key='_job_expires'  
ELSE
   insert into wordpress.wp_4_postmeta (post_id,meta_key,meta_value) values (3466,'_job_expires','2017-09-25')
```

and tried ROWCOUNT

```
UPDATE wordpress.wp_4_postmeta
SET meta_value='01-01-2685' 
WHERE  post_id=3471
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 
      INSERT INTO wordpress.wp_4_postmeta (post_id,meta_key,meta_value) 
      VALUES (3471,'_job_expires','2017-09-25')
```

**But with no luck. How can i do this in one query?**

I'm additionally attaching pictures of database table, to see what is going on. The post_id is not unique, there can be a lot of same post_id with different meta_key-s.

[image]

[image]

This is also tried, with `ON DUPLICATE KEY` BUT with no luck

```
insert into wordpress.wp_4_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) 
    values (3466, '_job_expires', '2011-06-25')
    on duplicate key update meta_value='2011-06-25';
```

with this i only got new row in my table as seen in picture below
[image]

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: There is no `IF` in SQL. Which DBMS product are you using?

Comment: you can do that with MERGE

Comment: db is mysql, as he is using Wordpress.

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name 
 im using mysql database

Answer (score 1):

The proper solution is `on duplicate key update`.

First, you need a unique key as `post_id, meta_key`:

```
create unique index unq_postmeta_post_metakey on wordpress.wp_4_postmeta(post_id, meta_key);
```

Then you can use `on duplicate key update`:

```
insert into wordpress.wp_4_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) 
    values (3466, '_job_expires', '2017-09-25')
    on duplicate key update meta_value='2017-06-25';
```

I note the two dates are different.  Is that intentional?

Comment: Dates are intentional, i was just testing if that works, i dont have a foreign key, there are several imputs with same post_id, but different meta_key, so i cant use ON DUPLICATE KEY

Comment: @Strahinja90bg . . . Of course you can.  That is what the unique index does.  I don't understand why you keep repeating that.

Comment: @ Gordon Linoff Thanks for your time, i attached two pictures in the original question so you can see what is the problem with this specific issue.

Comment: @Strahinja90bg . . . I don't see any duplicates on the `(post_id, meta_key)` pair.

Comment: i tried that already with ON DUPLICATE KEY, but it doesnt updates my row, it creates new one. I updated the original q so u can see

Comment: @Strahinja90bg . . . Did you create the unique index?  If so, then the values you are inserting are not really duplicates.